# How to create an array from key in multi-dimension array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The following array is stored in `$this->config->item('userlib_profile_fields')`

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [first_name] => First Name
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [family_name] => Family name
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [web_address] => Web Address
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [company_name] => Company Name
    )
...
...
)
```

I want to create an array from the above keys.

```
Array(first_name, family_name, web_address,company_name, .....)
```

I tried this but it give an errors.

```
$profile_columns = array();
foreach($this->config->item('userlib_profile_fields') as $value)
{
    foreach($value as $key=>$value)
    {
        //var_dump ($key);
        $profile_columns = array_push($profile_columns,$key);
    }
}
// error: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given
array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
```

Comment: Ok I will try, but sometimes I can't find any answer for my question. But this time, you got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example array that replicate yours.

```
$array = array(
    array('first_name' => 'First Name'),
    array('family_name' => 'Family Name'),
    array('web_address' => 'Web Address'),
    array('company_name' => 'Company Name')
);
```

loop and extract. (preserves array keys)

```
$items = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        $items[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

this will output

```
Array
(
    [first_name] => First Name
    [family_name] => Family Name
    [web_address] => Web Address
    [company_name] => Company Name
)
```

If you want to reset array keys to indexed array use this.

```
$items = array();
foreach($array as $item) {
    foreach($item as $key => $value) {
        $items[] = $value;
    }
}
```

this will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => First Name
    [1] => Family Name
    [2] => Web Address
    [3] => Company Name
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change**: `$profile_columns = array_push($profile_columns,$key);`
**To**: `array_push($profile_columns,$value);` **or** `$profile_columns[] = $value;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$test = array
(
array  (        'first_name' => 'First Name'    ),
array  (        'family_name' => 'Family name'  ),
array  (        'web_address' => 'Web Address'    ),
array  (        'company_name' => 'Company Name'    )
); 

$items = array();
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($test) ; $i++) {
    array_push($items,$test[$i][key($test[$i])]);
} 
print_r($items);
```

will give output like :

```
Array ( [0] => First Name [1] => Family name [2] => Web Address [3] => Company Name )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    $test = array
    (
    array  (        'first_name' => 'First Name'    ),
    array  (        'family_name' => 'Family name'  ),
    array  (        'web_address' => 'Web Address'    ),
    array  (        'company_name' => 'Company Name'    )
    );

$items = array();

for($i = 0 ; $i < count($test) ; $i++) {

array_push($items,$test[$i][key($test[$i])]);

}
```